# Kendo UI Sceduler, data bind

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

This is a 'getting set up and started' question.

I am trying to set up a KendoUI Scheduler, starting from this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline

No matter what I try, I can't get my internal server-side data to bind to the transport:read:url.

In the end, I took the data that is supplied by the demo url http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings and copied it exactly into a function on my server that returns it as a string. The demo doesn't work. Even if I amend the string so that it is json, not jsonp.

So really, my question is, in what format do I supply my data to the scheduler? What should it actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have low reputation to make a comment so i am posting this as an answer.

1) if you are using Kendo Scheduler Wrapper (Razor syntax) then you need to pass the data as KendoDataSourceResult.
2) If you are using Kendo scheduler Html / javascript syntax then you need to pass plain json.
 That will work

For further clearance can i get a snippet of what you have done and what you actually are trying to achieve?